# What do you call a text we append at the end of a work after it was published?

Tags: word-request

Sometimes, news articles, scientific articles and other works add a small text to correct certain things that were said, but happened to be wrong, so how do you call this type of text we append like that after it was initially published? I am not sure if the definition depends on the content, which in this case are corrections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's to correct errors, then it is an ***errata***. Some would insist that you should only use that if there are multiple errors, and if there's just one error it would be *erratum*, but that comes from a bizarre insistence of maintaining the grammar of Latin words when used in English - and there is a long, long convention of use in English that the separately-published or added-after-printing item that corrects errors is called an *errata*.

If it's not just correcting errors, there are various options. Personally, I favour ***addendum***.

Both terms come from Latin, obviously, but they are normal English words now.

Comment: +1 for "addendum".

Comment: "*Erratum*" is the singular; "*errata*" is plural.  The fact that the singular and plural still follow Latin rules suggest that they are still Latin words, not "normal English words".

Comment: @Jasper In my experience, in actual usage, *errata* is generally used regardless of number. You get little slips of paper added to books after printing with a single error corrected, and the heading "errata".